# Run api project as a background process C#

Tags: c#, testing

I'm setting up a test in a project that i'm working with. The test is supposed to consume two of the web-api's and one Azure function that is in the same solution as the test-project. Instead of having to start all these processes before being able to run the test, is there a way to have these 3 projects running in the background when running the test on your local machine?

I've been looking around and found "HostingEnvironment" to be interesting but I dont think that covers my need. 
If anyone could point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it.

Comment: You can set them up as a service so they are always running.  Then you need to communicate with the processes which can either be done use Sockets (TCP or UDP) or create pipes (streams) to IP in the processes.

Comment: Web API controllers can be tests simply by instantiating them and passing any required parameters in the constructor. There's no reason to start the entire service just to test a single controller action.

Comment: @jdweng, By service, do you mean I need to set it up as a local service on my own machine? I'll take a look at the TCP and UDP communication.

Comment: Can't tell where code is running from description.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create a service for your API.

```
sc create YourAPI binPath="C:\...\..exe" start=auto type=own
```

[Microsoft Docs - Sc create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/sc-create)